# getSupportActionBar.setTitle() не работает

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, actionbar, collapsing-toolbar-layout

В onCreate():

```
setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
```

Пытался установить заголовок так:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ActionBar bar1 = getSupportActionBar();
        bar1.setDisplayOptions(DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
        bar1.setTitle(title);
        bar1.setSubtitle(subtitle);
    }
}, 2000);
```

Мне нужно установить заголовок в мой тулбар, ни `getSupportActionBar.setTitle()`, ни `Activity.this.setTitle` не помогли.

**UPD**:

Тема:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/toolbar_drop_shadow</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: А какая у вас тема используется? Используете ли toolbar в верстке?

Comment: @pavel163 дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все проблема была в том, что мой тулбар находился в `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, у которого тоже есть метод [setTitle(CharSequence)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)). Из-за конфликта тулбара и `CollapsingToolbarLayout` я не мог установить title.

Решение было найдено в

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
```

[CollapsingToolbarLayout#setTitleEnabled(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setTitleEnabled(boolean))